# Why does subset of large named vector in R result in fatal error?

Tags: r, subset

I have two large named vectors and want to subset `bar` to give a vector that only includes those elements matching named elements in `foo`.

The data look like this:

```
# foo
> length(foo)
[1] 51174

> foo[1:10]
  the    to     a   you   and    of     i    is  that    in 
25499 24985 23053 22064 20687 16042 15351 13776 13714  9995 

> names(foo[1:10])
[1] "the"  "to"   "a"    "you"  "and"  "of"   "i"    "is"   "that" "in"  

# bar
> length(bar)
[1] 3755242

> bar[1:10]
     the       of       to      and        a       in       is     that      for        i 
16330164  9263180  8295547  8159378  6391771  5410076  3585765  3531807  2881175  2465688 

> names(bar[1:10])
[1] "the"  "of"   "to"   "and"  "a"    "in"   "is"   "that" "for"  "i"
```

To subset, I have previously used the following method without issue on the same data:

`bar[names(foo)]`

However, using this same method, I am now receiving an **"R Session Aborted** R encountered a fatal error" message unpredictably. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. How do I avoid causing a fatal error? Is this a memory issue?

Comment: Even if there is a memory issue, R shouldn't crash. What is your `sessionInfo()`? What has changed on your system setup?

Comment: R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

I have recently switched machines but I'm getting the same issue on an older machine, too. It's very odd...

Comment: Do you have the same issue with R 4.1.0? This might be something to be reported to the R-devel mailing list but you need a reproducible example.

Comment: Same problem with 4.1.0.

Really strange. Thanks @Roland.

Comment: Error not there with 4.0.1, though! Will contact the dev team.